# Redshift of Cosmic Microwave Background

Tags: cosmology, photons, cosmic-microwave-background

Does the cosmic microwave background radiation have a red shift parameter z?  If so what is the value for z?

Answer (score 10):

The cosmic microwave background has a redshift of about $1100$, see [here](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept02/Kinney/Kinney3.html) for instance.

Keep in mind that the "surface of last scattering" that gives rise to the CMB in fact existed everywhere in space, it's just that the photons currently reaching us have $z\sim1100$.